# Checksum token in system email "Memberships - Receipt (on-line)" causes critical error

Tags: email, tokens, smarty, system-workflow-messages

When using a checksum token in a receipt email like this:

> [http://example.org/?page=CiviCRM&q=civicrm/contribute/transact&reset=1&id=IDNUMBER&{contact.checksum}&cid={contact.contact_id}](http://example.org/?page=CiviCRM&q=civicrm/contribute/transact&reset=1&id=IDNUMBER&%7Bcontact.checksum%7D&cid=%7Bcontact.contact_id%7D)

A critical error is thrown in wc-logs but no specifics are included in the error message:

> CRITICAL Smarty error: [in string

Are system emails parsed differently? My plan at the moment is to switch over to CiviRules which work with said tokens.

Comment: if you remove the link the receipt works?

Comment: Correct. Using these tokens breaks the system template emails:

https://www.wordpress-website-example.com/my-account/?{contact.checksum}&cid={contact.contact_id}&mid={membership.id}

Answer (score 1):

According to the [documentation](https://docs.civicrm.org/user/en/latest/common-workflows/tokens-and-mail-merge/#checksum) they should look like

> WordPress (with Clean URLs): [http://example.org/civicrm/contribute/transact?reset=1&id=IDNUMBER&{contact.checksum}&cid={contact.contact_id}](http://example.org/civicrm/contribute/transact?reset=1&id=IDNUMBER&%7Bcontact.checksum%7D&cid=%7Bcontact.contact_id%7D)

> WordPress (without Clean URLs): [http://example.org/?civiwp=CiviCRM&q=civicrm/contribute/transact&reset=1&id=IDNUMBER&{contact.checksum}&cid={contact.contact_id}](http://example.org/?civiwp=CiviCRM&q=civicrm/contribute/transact&reset=1&id=IDNUMBER&%7Bcontact.checksum%7D&cid=%7Bcontact.contact_id%7D)

There may be a good reason yours does not but thought I should record this.

Comment: The critical error doesn't have to do with how the links are structured but with how the tokens are parsed.